# Issue creating a Secret in Kubernetes using the Golang client

Tags: go, kubernetes

I have the following code:

```
secret, err = d.serviceClient.Secrets(namespace).Get(secret.Name, metav1.GetOptions{})
if err != nil {
    // If not found, create a new secret
    if _, err := d.serviceClient.Secrets(namespace).Create(secret); err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "error creating user secrets")
    }
}
```

And the code generating a secret:

```
func generateDatabaseSecret(message types.Deployment) *apiv1.Secret {
    data := map[string][]byte{
        "TEST":     []byte("test"),
    }
    object := metav1.ObjectMeta{Name: "test"}
    secret := &v1.Secret{Data: data, ObjectMeta: object}

    output, _ := json.Marshal(secret)
    log.Println(string(output))
    return secret
```

}

However when I run the above against my Kubernetes cluster, I get the following error:

```
 error creating user secrets: Secret "" is invalid: metadata.name: Required value: name or generateName is required
```

Even though the JSON encoded secret is as followed:

```
{"metadata":{"name":"test","creationTimestamp":null},"data":{"TEST":"bG9jYWxsb3N0"}
```

Am I missing something super obvious here? It doesn't make any sense

Comment: It doesn't look like your code is calling `generateDatabaseSecret`; it's calling the `Create` method with the (probably zero-valued) `secret` that got returned from the failing `Get` call.

Comment: Oh my god you're absolutely correct! Silly me!

Answer (score 0):

As David Maze sad in comments, you calling the wrong method `Create` instead of `generateDatabaseSecret`.